# Javascript with COM object

Tags: javascript, html, com, autohotkey

I am writing an automation script using AHK and have already gone through their forums and live chat to no avail.

My issue is that I am using a COM object to navigate and click things on a webpage. But the navigation menu on the webpage does not change url's when going to another part of the website. Instead they use a "main controller" so the url in the address bar never changes but the webpage does.

I do not have access to the source code but from the element inspector in the web browser I know the name of the javascript function and the arguments it calls to go to the page I want.

I am wondering if there is a way, through the com object or other method, to call the javascript function even though I do not have direct access to the source code?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course there is.  Just have your script access the address bar and past in the script.  E.g.:

```
javascript:alert("Hello World");
```

And note, some browsers may strip out the first part and give you back a search result, so you may have to have AHK, after typing/pasting in the command, go back to the beginning and re-type the `javascript:` part.

Now, whether this works when you call a function up without referencing back to the source, I can't say, but then again, you could have given more details in your post.

Comment: I have just tried that and all it does is return to the page I was originally on. I guess I dont really know what more details I can give to you. I cannot navigate a webpage because the buttons call a javascript function and the url does not change. So I have no way to get to a new webpage without physical interaction.

Then again, that's all in the original post.

Comment: What website? What doe the Button code do?  The devil is in the details.  If the page delivery is framed, or AJAX or some such thing, you will have to find a way to have AHK "click" the button, maybe `Send {Click xpos, ypos, [button], [numberofclicks]}`

Comment: It's a website you have to log into so you wont be able to do anything with it unless you are able to login. As I stated the button you need to click shows when you hover over the menu. This needs to be a generic script so I cannot specify an exact x and y as the screen size this is used on may change. Also explained above is that the button code calls a javascript function that changes the webpage. But I do not have access to the source, also stated above, so I would not be able to tell you what exactly it does.

Comment: I still say it is possible to do what you want. Just not by executing a javascript. I use a time entry application ("Bill4Time") that has a table of daily time entries and a row to enter a new one (so obviously, that row is in a different place after entries are made). Unfortunately, the element I need to click to edit an entry (looks like a button, but not using html button tag) does not have an ID or Class assigned. Nonetheless, by searching the row element class for specific text, and moving down a few child elements, I can "click" on that button in AHK. So can you. Good luck, and have fun!

Comment: So I have all the html code/js code for the website via the website inspector. I can post it if you think you would be able to analyze it and see if you can figure anything out.